# Xamarin set up IOS build host

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am using visual studio for Xamarin development and I have a business license for both Android and IOS. The Android version of my project is nearing completion and I want to begin development on the IOS version.

I am following the process listed in the requirements and installation section of the below link: 
http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/introduction_to_xamarin_ios_for_visual_studio/

I have added my Apple Account ID to XCode however as far as I can tell you need to manually assign an IOS Certificate to the build hosts keychain to beable to build from visual studio

> If you are using Visual Studio for Xamarin.iOS development, you also
>   have the option of provisioning manually using the Apple Developer
>   Portal.

Now as far as I can tell this has a $99 cost involved? Is this fee mandatory before I can build any IOS apps from visual studio ?

EDIT:

After pairing the build host and building my app it seems my suspicions are confirmed. A IOS Development Certificate
stored in the keychain is required

Answer (score 3):

As far as i know you don't actually need the iOS Certificates for developing with Visual Studio and the build host, as long as you're running your app on the iOS simulator. However, as soon as you want to test your app on a real device you need the certificates. And just a reminder, you should test on real devices as soon as possible. I got some really bad surprises after developing exclusively on the simulator for more than 6 weeks ...